# C++ Multiple inheritence, base class visibility and the dreaded diamond. Re-exposing ancestor base class as public?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, access-specifier

I need to abstract away a lot of the interface from a base class by making it protected, but I also need public access to a simple ancestor class `Object`. Can I negotiate the [dreaded diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8) without write/edit access to these ancestors and still present only a basic API but make `Object`'s API public again?

```
class Object {
    virtual bool  Equals (const Object &obj) const;
    virtual int  GetHashCode (void) const;
};

class ComplicatedOne : public Object {
    //Lots of funcs I don't want or need.
};

class Line : protected ComplicatedOne, public Object {
    //Some funcs of ComplicatedOne get re-implemented or called by alias here
public:
    virtual bool Equals(const Object &obj) const {
        return Object::Equals(obj);
    }
    virtual int GetHashCode() const {
        return Object::GetHashCode();
    }
};

class Array {
    void Add (Object &obj);
    Object *GetAt (int i);
};

main() {
    Array a;
    a.Add(new Line());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use composition.

You can hold an instance of `ComplicatedOne` as a member, and expose what you need.

This way you can keep it protected, but will never have a Diamond situation.

Besides, If `ComplicatedOne`  is an `Object`, so `Line` is an `Object` by inheritance, so you don't need to inherit again.

Answer (score 1):

You are very vague about what your real problem is, but to me it sounds as if you want to use inheritance just to get code reuse.
You should not do this. Have a look at this [article](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinhP.html).
To me it sound as if composition is more what you want. Create a member of your `ComplicatedOne` in your class Line and delegate the calls to this member. Then you don't need to inherit from it.

Comment: True, I'm going OO mad with inheritence when composition is called for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return Object::Equals(obj);
```

That cannot compile, because it is ambiguous: **there are two `Object` base objects.**

Also, conversion from `Line*` to `Object*` is ambiguous, and the ambiguity cannot be resolved to the second `Object` base class (in left to right base class order), so the second `Object` base does not serve any purpose except to create difficulties.

It is not clear what you are trying to do exactly: what does the `ComplicatedOne` class represent? Why do you inherit from it, if you are going to override every `Object` virtual function again?

Comment: Though `ComplicateOne` contains `//Lots of funcs I don't want or need.`, it has still has its uses.